# Load a component's CSS only if it is rendered

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

In a project, i have different components with different css imports and in the app i use react-router to define the paths. When I access /anycomponent i have their imports in the head, but all the css of the other components also go there. Is there any way to import a component's css only when it is rendered?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import component1 from './pages/component1';
import component2 from './pages/component2';

export default function Routes() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={component1} />
                <Route path="/component2" component={component2} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Surely it's better to aggregate CSS as much as possible so that when a component renders, you don't have to also load a CSS file?

Comment: I already have 10 style tags on my head, and i'm not even 5% from the end, i would like to avoid this unnecessary amount of imports on my head. It would improve performance too.

Comment: How are you styling your components? Are you creating CSS files manually or using some form of CSS-in-JS like Emotion?

Comment: I'm creating the css files manually, one for each component.

Comment: You should really look into using CSS-in-JS such as Emotion, Styled Components, or something similar. If you're creating separate files, you're bloating your repo and making the code harder to maintain. Emotion is great for creating component-specific CSS and Emotion handles all the CSS bundling for you at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy loading the component:

```
const Component1 = lazy(() => import('./pages/component1'));
const Component2 = lazy(() => import('./pages/component2'));

<BrowserRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Component1 }/>
        <Route path="/component2" component={Component2 }/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
</BrowserRouter>
```